# Oracle error ORA-25188 spontaneously appearing for unknown reasons

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

A remote installation of some software using Oracle 11.2 is being reported with the following errors:

- ORA-25188: cannot drop/disable/defer the primary key constraint for
  index-organized tables or sorted hash cluster

These errors seem to be happening everywhere.  Even for basic inserts.  As far as I can tell, I don't drop or alter any indexes in my IOT tables. And I've never had any issues like this in the past few years (the software hasn't changed much). The other thing I should mention is that these errors just started popping up after several days of error-free activity.

So I got a dump of the entire schema.  I then imported it into my own Oracle system, and connected my application to it.  Everything works fine!  I don't have easy access to the actual system, so I am not able to investigate directly.

Is there any indirect reason why the system could be generating ORA-25188 or some bad state that could cause this error?

Comment: Does the problematic installation have any database-level triggers? Though can't imagine why they would be doing anything that could lead to this. Or any invalid objects that are attempting recompilation and failing - probably not in your schema, from what you've said. Wild guesses, clearly...

Answer (score 0):

Try to [`PURGE RECYCLEBIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#i1011357) or `PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN`, this can help in some situations.
For second variant you must logon [`as sysdba`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_sysdba.htm).